# Github pages: Image shows correctly in markdown, not on website

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I am using Github Pages + Jekyll for a blog. I'd love your help!

I just uploaded a post, including an image. After I commit changes I can see the picture properly displayed within the preview, but not in the browser. I also checked on a different browser and on my phone to ensure its not my cache or sth like that.

Code:

How it looks on Github preview:
[image: preview]

This is how the image shows on my browser:
[image]

I saved the file in the folder images where the .md file is located.

Link to the full code [here](https://github.com/financenerd/financenerd.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2019-12-26-Best-bank-accounts-in-Switzerland.md)

Link to the blogpost [here](https://financenerd.github.io//2019/12/26/Best-bank-accounts-in-Switzerland.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make PR. 
This is raw url. 
Please check this.

https://github.com/financenerd/financenerd.github.io/pull/1/files

Comment: I accepted the changes and it again showed correctly in the preview, but after build it didnt show properly on the website itself..

Comment: @Financenerd I fixed conflict merge plz

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll does not copy assets placed in the _posts folder. Therefore your image is missing after build.

You have to put the image in another folder (not starting with an underscore). Like  `/assets/img/` or `/assets/images` at the root of your project.

Then in your post, in markdown

`![image](/assets/img/ZAK.JPEG)`

or

`![image]({{site.baseurl}}/assets/img/ZAK.JPEG)`

With Github page, you also have this option: https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll-postfiles/ but I can't speak for experience.

Comment: Thank you! I added the JPEG file into the assets folder as suggested and created a new line in my post: <img src="../assets/images/ZAK.JPEG">  The link to the file works, however, after build I still have the same issue, see: https://financenerd.github.io//2019/12/26/Best-bank-accounts-in-Switzerland.html